# How to check if lat long position is within or contained by boundary from Google Maps data-driven styling from custom KML dataset

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

As per this [codepen](https://codepen.io/TinyTuna/pen/ZEPyWZJ) I have created a Google map using the Maps Javascript API.

I have then added a number of custom postcodes boundaries to this using the [data-driven styling for data sets (Preview) feature](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/dds-datasets/overview)

I then added a search box using the [places search API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) and [advanced markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/advanced-markers/overview).

I now need to check if the result from the places search is contained within the data driven styling dataset and so I can display information about delivery costs available for the location the user searched for.

Can anyone please advise how I can do this?

KML file can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/hd9xqg2whugnp9pyzekm0/stack-overflow-postcodes.kml?rlkey=7i3yt02gqw2zisle670q15d90&dl=0):

I see there's a [containsLocation()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation) function in the Geometry library, but that seems to require creating a polygon from a path from co-ordinates. My KML file contains many regions (multiple postcodes) and is hosted is cloud console as per advise [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/dds-datasets/create-dataset)

Edit: Updated with codepen [here](https://codepen.io/TinyTuna/pen/ZEPyWZJ) and kml file above.

Thank you

```js
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright 2019 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */
// Initialize and add the map
// let map;

async function initMap() {
  // The location of UK
  // const position = { lat: 51.50630746850154, lng: -0.1393693718019947 }; // London
  const position = { lat: 51.611060072110845, lng: -0.59 }; 

  // Request needed libraries.
  //@ts-ignore
  const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary('maps');
  const { AdvancedMarkerElement, PinElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary(
    'marker'
  );
  const { places } = await google.maps.importLibrary('places');

  // The map, centered at UK
  const mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
  const options = {
    mapId: 'a7a2b6274c1716e2',
    zoom: 8,
    center: position,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,

    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER,
    },

    fullscreenControl: true,
    fullscreenControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER,
    },
    // zoomControlOptions: {
    //   position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM,
    // },

    // Restrict map bounds and zoom
    maxZoom: 9.5,
    minZoom: 7,
    restriction: {
      latLngBounds: {
        north: 59,
        south: 48,
        east: 6,
        west: -12,
      },
    },
  };

  const map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, options);

  // Add Custom Postcode Data Set
  const PostcodeDatasetId = '33f0902c-7f7d-4e84-b832-0997e0567100';
  // Add layer
  const DatasetLayer = map.getDatasetFeatureLayer(PostcodeDatasetId);

  DatasetLayer.style = (params) => {
    return {
      fillColor: '#ffffff',
      fillOpacity: 0.7,
      // pointRadius: 3,
      strokeColor: 'green',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 1,
    };
  };


  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  const input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  const searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(input);
  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', () => {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  let markers = [];

  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', () => {
    const places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach((marker) => {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    places.forEach((place) => {
      if (!place.geometry || !place.geometry.location) {
        console.log('Returned place contains no geometry');
        return;
      }

      const icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50),
        zIndex: 6000,
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      markers.push(
        new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerView({
          map,
          content: new PinElement({
            scale: 1.5,
          }).element,
          title: place.name,
          position: place.geometry.location,
        })
      );
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
}

initMap();
```

Comment: I don't see any way to access the polygons from the data-driven styling data on the map.  The only way I know to do what you want is to parse the KML data with a 3rd party KML parser (like [geoxml3](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3)) to create `google.maps.Polygon` objects, then use the `containsLocation` method in the API with those polygons.

Comment: Time for a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:188853).

Comment: Thank @geocodezip, after reading a bit more I think you're right. It would have to be geoxml3 to convert to a google maps polygon. For now I've decided to change my approach and use the new Routes API to draw a path from the distribution center to the customer postcode. That was we can just calculate price based on an accurate distance instead of postcode regions, which is probably better anyway.

Comment: Good idea @MrUpsidown, done: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/321690040